# mediaelement.js - no volume control shows up using the typical wordpress shortcode [audio src=""]

Tags: mediaelement.js

**`mediaelement.js`** - is there a wordpress plugin shortcode option for audio volume control? My graphic shows no volume control.  The sample graphic on the [**mediaelement**](http://mediaelement.com/) shows a working audio volume control.

My typical shortcode is: **`[audio src="url"]`**

I tried **`[audio src="url" volume="true"]`** - but, still no volume control.

The issue is the same for Firefox and IE.